# Font awesome icons 4.7 version not displaying android

Tags: android, font-awesome

I'm using fontawesome library from below link,

https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify

but some of the Font awesome icons 4.7 version not displaying. Could you please suggest me any idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out my blog post (works on latest android)  - https://niveditagautam.wordpress.com/2018/10/15/adding-font-awesome-to-your-android-app

Answer (score 0):

Iconify uses Font Awesome v. 4.5 therefore icons from 4.7 are not available.

You either need to wait for library update or do it by yourself and create a PR to give back to community :)

(Note that updating Iconify looks pretty straightforward, just replace .ttf with newer file and add new icons [here](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify/blob/master/android-iconify-fontawesome/src/main/java/com/joanzapata/iconify/fonts/FontAwesomeIcons.java))

Comment: @ Rafal Zawadzki Thanks for your response. I have added the new icons in the file  already like you mentioned. could please tell me what you mean as PR and .ttf?

Comment: `.ttf` is font file extension, `PR` is `Pull Request` in git (request to include your changes into master branch, eg. to include your updates in Iconify)

Comment: Zawadzki okay Thank you i will check and let you know.